# Why doesent this sqlquestion work(phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

(I am using PHPmyadmin)

```
SELECT answered,rightOrWrong,`quiz`.quizID,`users`.name,`quiz`.name 
FROM `quizresults`, `users`, `quizes` 
WHERE `users`.uID=`quizresults`.uID 
AND `quizes`.quizID=`quizresults`.quizID
```

I want to get this elements:
answered,

```
rightOrWrong,
`quiz`.quizID,
`users`.name,
`quiz`.name.
```

But for some reason the sql window telling me `#1054 - Unknown column 'quiz.quizID' in 'field list'`

Comment: Can you show us the table definition? You may just have a typo. And why do you only backtick some of the elements?

Comment: It is like the error states: Your `quiz` table doesn't have a column named `quizID`. Maybe it's just called `id` or double check for lower/uppper case errors.

Comment: The columns in the tabel are:
  qID  question  rightAnswer  wrongAnswer  quizID  and i just want the quizID

Comment: Look at @ThorstenDittmar's answer below - it explains quite clearly what went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Quiz` table in your `from`-clause. Only a `Quizes` table. Thus MySql does not know it.